# Android coding guideline for private FINAL static variable names

Tags: android, coding-style

So i get that private vars start with 's' like

```
private static int sSomeInt;
```

but what about those that are also `final` ?

i like that `public static final` variable names are in all caps, since it seems to me that i can't modify a variable in all-caps. for me, these two feel too much the same to me, even though they're supposed to be different?

```
private static int sMutableInt;
private static final int sImmutableInt;
```

and i can't tell by the style of the variable name itself that i can't re-assign `sImmutableInt` (only by the actual name of it)

1. does Android not care about these? (not mentioned in https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html
2. what is a common practice for this case?

Comment: Are you specifically talking about changes to open source Android code that you may make a contribution for?  That is the only place where the "rules" apply (not to an application you may develop that runs on Android).

Comment: sure, but i'd like to adhere to those suggestions anyways for my own apps/code. i guess that makes me a communist, but i prefer standardization for coding

Answer (score 3):

The source code generally `USES_ALL_CAPS_AND_UNDERSCORES` for all `static final` data members, whether public or private.

Comment: All caps with underscores is for PUBLIC static final <type>  constants. So the case in the original question would match the "rule".  (sImmutableInt)

Comment: hmmm this seems correct, and more intuitive. out of curiosity, how many occasions have you seen this? ( more than 30?)

Comment: @DavidT.: More times than I can count. You are welcome to review the Android source code and see this pattern in use, such as [in `AsyncTask`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) and [`Activity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java). To flip it around, I cannot recall ever seeing a `static final` *not* using `THE_ALL_CAPS_AND_UNDERSCORES` style.

Comment: @CommonsWare awesome. i just wanted to make sure. yeah i agree, that's what i saw in a lot of android source code also. leaving this answer unaccepted for a little bit longer to see if anyone else has any interesting perspectives that are different (since this question is slightly subjective)

Answer (score 2):

That basically depends on the Java code convention you stick to. Android source code and its SDK use the all caps and underscore convention for constants.

I guess that Android is following *Google Java Style*:
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html

About your question:

```
// Constants
static final int NUMBER = 5;
static final ImmutableList<String> NAMES = ImmutableList.of("Ed", "Ann");
static final Joiner COMMA_JOINER = Joiner.on(',');  // because Joiner is immutable
static final SomeMutableType[] EMPTY_ARRAY = {};
enum SomeEnum { ENUM_CONSTANT }

// Not constants
static String nonFinal = "non-final";
final String nonStatic = "non-static";
static final Set<String> mutableCollection = new HashSet<String>();
static final ImmutableSet<SomeMutableType> mutableElements = ImmutableSet.of(mutable);
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.getName());
static final String[] nonEmptyArray = {"these", "can", "change"};
```

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2.4-constant-names

For instance, you can check the the `View` class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE).

```
public static final int GONE = ...
```